# How to configure code climate to ignore lines of code with log statements

Tags: typescript, code-climate

Is it possible to configure code climate, so it does not count lines only logging?

I like the idea of having a threshold per function, lets say 25 lines, but adding verbose logging should not create a code climate issue in my opinion.